# Page Content Messed up After Moving File to a new location HTML

Tags: html, css, file, directory

So I have never had this happen before but I moved an html file I have been working on to a new location on my computer. When I run the file, all the content has been messed up. It almost looks like there is no css styling to it or anything. But when I open up the exact same file in the original location, everything is perfect.

I even opened both files and copied/pasted from the perfect file to the messed up one and it still does the same thing. Has anyone ever heard of this or encountered this before? I am still trying to fix it and would appreciate any help.

UPDATE:

So I moved all of the CSS into the header of the html file. I opened the file and it was fine. Looked good. I copied the file and pasted it into a different folder and opened it and its partly messed up. I ran a compare program and the files match exactly. Not a single thing different. Even If I put the original document in another location it still messes up.

Comment: Is it a web saved html file? Need more information.

Comment: did you check if the link to the css file is correct?

Comment: The link to the css file is correct. so no problems there. The html file is not a web saved file. I have started working on it from scratch using a text editor and just saved it as an .html

Comment: Let us see the part of the HTML code where you link to the CSS file (both versions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay So I finally figured the problem out. I am working on a terminal and when I save my work to my teams folder on the server the css is not being applied properly but when I save my work on my desktop and run it from there everything is working out just fine. Sent the files to someone else and they tried both ways and turns out we just can not run the files from our teams folder on the server. Thanks to everyone who answered and tried to help out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have missed to copy the dependency files.